# When using L2 regularization outside of linear regression, do the same MAP estimation assumptions hold?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, regularization

Some context is shared below, and my question is **bolded** at the end.

---

### MLE from observation noise

In the linear regression setting, we learn model weights $\mathbf{w}$ to make scalar predictions $\hat{y}$ from samples $\mathbf{x}$ as

$$
\hat{y} = \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}
$$

When one assumes the true underlying distribution is a linear combination and a Gaussian noise term,

$$
y|\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x} + \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)
$$

then maximum likelihood estimation (MLE) induces a mean squared error loss

$$
\mathcal{L}_{MLE}(\mathbf{w}) = \sum_{i=1}^n (\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}_i - y)^2
$$

such that minimizing $\mathcal{L}_{MLE}$ produces the MLE estimate of weights.

### MAP from weight distribution

Further, if one assumes a Gaussian prior distribution on the model weights $\mathbf{w}$ with each weight $w_i$ having identical variance $\nu^2$

$$
w_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \nu^2)
$$

then the analogous maximum a posteriori (MAP) estimation induces the L2 regularizer with regularization weight $\lambda = \frac{\sigma^2}{\nu^2}$

$$
\mathcal{L}_{MAP}(\mathbf{w}) = \sum_{i=1}^n (\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}_i - y)^2 + \lambda||\mathbf{w}||^2_2
$$

such that minimizing $\mathcal{L}_{MAP}$ produces the MAP estimate of weights.

I really appreciate that these common practices can be derived from first principles and simple distributional assumptions.

But L2 regularization is used all over the place - practitioners will add an L2 loss on the weights for models of all sorts, from logistic regression to enormous neural networks.  I appreciate that it works well, but it seems a bit mysterious.  **When used outside of the linear regression setting, does L2 regularization still express elegant distributional assumptions and first-principles?**

Comment: The posterior is proportional to the likelihood times the prior. Whatever loss the likelihood corresponds to, the prior will add the same squared quadratic term.

Comment: So if the loss is induced by some likelihood, then a gaussian prior induces L2 regularization.  Right?  And what if the loss is not induced by some likelihood?  e.g. some sloppily applied (or even pathological) loss.

Comment: If your likelihood is pathological, of course there are no guarantees. But $\ell_2$ regularization can be helpful for tough losses because it increases the convexity of your function.

Comment: @JohnMadden when you say a pathological likelihood affords no guarantees, do you mean we can also lose the guarantee of L2 regularization being MAP-derived from a Gaussian prior on weights?  Even though the loss is still MLE-derived from a likelihood?

Comment: @kdbanman Oh I should have said "loss is pathological", sorry I just misquoted you. Surely we can think of pathological losses that would make $\ell_2$ regularization unreasonable; namely, losses that require whatever we are $\ell_2$ penalizing to be high. But yes, if you have a likelihood, and even in some more general cases, you can think of it as a gaussian prior. You may find useful results outside of likelihood-based approaches by googling for "Inverse Problems".

Comment: Ah, very interesting!  Thank you.  I'm interested in alternative theoretical approaches to regularization, like [regularizers being derived via robustness constraints](https://jmlr.org/papers/volume19/17-295/17-295.pdf), so I will look up the inverse problems you suggest.